# ASP.Net Code Optimization

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, optimization, web-applications

I have almost every piece of code, I just need it to be optimized using correct IF_ELSE conditions and arranging the right flow.
I have a webform (UserProfile.aspx), which contains FormView (to display user profile).
In FormView ItemTemplate, I have put simple HTML  and ASP.Net Labels to display Info using Label's Text property :
    Eval("col_name");

In EditItemTemplate, I have same table with but textboxes instead of Labels.

I have a button "Edit", on its Click event, I'm changing FormViewMode
    FormView1.changeMode(FormViewMode.Edit); [ WORKING ]

I have another button "Cancel", on its Click event, I'm changing FormViewMode
    FormView1.changeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly); [ <-- NOT WORKING ]

To display user profile, I'm passing user-id from querystring (querystring field = "user")
So the valid URL looks like :
    /UserProfile.aspx?user=121

What I want to achieve is :

```
If (user_IS_Logged_In)
//Some basic tasks like setting welcome message label with username/email etc.


If (querystring_is_EMPTY OR querystring_field_is_incorrect OR user_IS_NOT_Logged_IN)
//Remove the Edit and Cancel buttons


If (querystring_field_is_exist)
//initialize user_id (this will be passed to ShowUserDetails(user_id))


If (user_IS_Logged_In AND querystring_is_exist)
If querystring value and logged in user_id ARE NOT EQUAL THEN
//Again Remove the Edit and Cancel buttons
```

P.S --> I'm thinking to add an UpdatePanel around the FormView Once I achieve above tasks, for consistent look.

I know the problem is quite difficult to understand so feel free to ask details.
I will provide the code as needed.

Comment: edit your code and please format it, its very difficult to read it

Comment: yes, I know its difficult, but I can't optimize even the question anymore. Please ask the details here.

Comment: I mean just edit your question and format the code portions that are present in this question in stack overflow style ,

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't find it in the new stackoverflow design. Hope you meant putting code in <code></code> like older stackoverflow ?